# Where to put include_type_name in config.exs

Tags: elasticsearch, elixir

I want to create an Elasticsearch 7.x index from my elixir config.exs file:

```
config :app_core, App.Tools.ElasticsearchCluster,
  url: System.get_env("ELASTIC_HOST"),
  # username: "username",
  # password: "password",
  api: Elasticsearch.API.HTTP,
  json_library: Poison,
  indexes: %{
    indie: %{
      settings: "priv/elasticsearch/indies.json",
      store: App.Tools.ElasticSearch.Indie.Store,
      sources: [App.Data.Schema.Indie],
      bulk_page_size: 5000,
      bulk_wait_interval: 15_000
    }
  }
```

The `priv/elasticsearch/indies.json` begins with

```
{
  "mappings": {
     "_doc":    {
      "properties": {
        "category" : {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties" : {
```

However, when I try to create the index, I get error

```
"The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true."
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem in the context I referenced (Putting it in front of a specific query won't work)?

Upon request from Assael Azran, here is the full indies.json:

```
{
  "mappings": {
     "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "category" : {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "all_parents" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "direct_parent" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "paths" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "slug": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "parent_id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "index": false
        },
        "images": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "indie_url": {
              "type": "text",
              "index": false
            }
          }
        },
        "tenant": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "suggest_keywords": {
          "type": "completion",
          "contexts": [
            {
                "name": "tenant",
                "type": "category"
            }
          ]
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": false
        },
        "updated_at": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "string_facet": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_facet": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Mapping types are no longer supported in versions 7.x.

> Elasticsearch 7.x
>   Specifying types in requests is deprecated. For instance, indexing a document no longer requires a document type. The new index APIs are PUT {index}/_doc/{id} in case of explicit ids and POST {index}/_doc for auto-generated ids. Note that in 7.0, _doc is a permanent part of the path, and represents the endpoint name rather than the document type.
>   The include_type_name parameter in the index creation, index template, and mapping APIs will default to false. Setting the parameter at all will result in a deprecation warning.
>   The *default* mapping type is removed.

My suggestion is to remove `_doc` type from your mappings.

> {
>       "mappings": {
>             "properties": {
>               "category" : {
>                 "type": "nested",
>                 "properties" : {

[From here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html)

**UPDATE**

Tested on elastic 7.2.0

I've tried to create the following mappings:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "category": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "all_parents": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "direct_parent": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "paths": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "slug": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "parent_id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "index": false
        },
        "images": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "indie_url": {
              "type": "text",
              "index": false
            }
          }
        },
        "tenant": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "suggest_keywords": {
          "type": "completion",
          "contexts": [
            {
              "name": "tenant",
              "type": "category"
            }
          ]
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": false
        },
        "updated_at": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "string_facet": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_facet": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And as expected i get this error:

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true."
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true."
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

When i remove `_doc` from mappings:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "category": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "all_parents": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "direct_parent": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "paths": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "slug": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "parent_id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "index": false
        },
        "images": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "indie_url": {
              "type": "text",
              "index": false
            }
          }
        },
        "tenant": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "suggest_keywords": {
          "type": "completion",
          "contexts": [
            {
              "name": "tenant",
              "type": "category"
            }
          ]
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": false
        },
        "updated_at": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "string_facet": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_facet": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I get this

```
{

"acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true,
  "index" : "my_index"
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it then gives me a postgrex error, indicating that it cannot determine the datatype.

Comment: Can you post your full mapping?

Comment: Unfortunately, your proposition with the default_options, while sounding very promising, doesn't work either.

Comment: Please share your full mappings.

Comment: I have added the mapping to the original post.

Comment: Hi, i updated my answer based on your mappings. see **UPDATE** section.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I will mark the question as answered as I have not indicated that I had tried to get rid of the mapping type definition but got a postgrex error of undetermined datatype.